# Use of addresses

Tags: transaction

When you want to do several transactions how do you update the people transacting with you of your new address? In the case of machines transacting with each other how will the machines know the address of the other machines if the address changes every time that a new transaction is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the problem some applications or projects would encounter. IOTA Foundation has post a series of [proposal for reusable address](https://blog.iota.org/a-proposal-for-reusable-addresses-part1-bc6dbca84cbf), so we may see this solution in the near future.

As for now, we still have to deal with this issue. There is already a second layer solution called [IOTA-Pay](https://medium.com/coinmonks/reusable-addresses-with-iota-pay-38c4b3f10333). But as I said it's on top of the first layer which doesn't actually solve in the base protocol.

I was also trying a method which [tracking address](https://iotastrong.io/track/) instead. The idea is if a transaction bundle has remainder address, we can keep tracking it because remainder address will always belongs to owner. But the downside is sender has to always not sending all funds in the address or the bundle won't contain transaction for remainder address.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. Did you implement the tracking address system?

Comment: I didn't, the link I post just some thoughts and experiments.